# Enterprise Library 5 Validation Assigning Priorities

Tags: c#, .net, validation, enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise Library 5 validation application block for enterprise validation needs.  I wonder, if there is any way to assign priorities to the validation rules applied to a field using data annotations.

Comment: Why would you want to? Surely an item is only valid if it passes all the validations?

Comment: We designed the product to display only one validation error related to a field at a time. And customer insists on having priority between validation rules. You are right and if I were to decide, I would simply say this does not make sense at all; but as you can guess I have no effect on such critical decisions:)

Comment: You can extend the validation application block components. Presumably you can use this ability to add a priority attribute, but I've never tried, because it's daft :)